# ¿Cómo usar HttpGet en android?

Tags: android-studio, phpmyadmin

Tengo un archivo `php` en el cual debo introducir un ID para generar una consulta específica. He creado una variable `HttpGet` `Obtener = new HttpGet();` y quiero insertarle el parámetro desde una aplicación en android para que me devuelva los datos que yo deseo ¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lanza la petición a tu php mediante un `AsyncTask` desde tu aplicación:

```
public class HttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{       

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)   
{           
    BufferedReader inBuffer = null;
    String url = "http://tudireccion/tuphp.php";
    String result = "fail";
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", params[0]));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                postParameters);

        request.setEntity(formEntity);
         httpClient.execute(request);
                result="got it";

    } catch(Exception e) {

        result = e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        if (inBuffer != null) {
            try {
                inBuffer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return  result;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String page)
{       
     //Lo que recibes después de ejecutar la peticion
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), page,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  toast.show();
   }   

}
```

Para ejecutar el AsynkTask:

```
new HttpPost().execute(new String[] {name});
```